# Update record based on group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a list of rows:

```
 public class Row 
{
    public string SINo{ get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int FreeGoods { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

and these records:

```
  SINo          AccountName       ProductCode       Quantity       FreeGoods
S145144       DUMAN, MARILYN M.    13002154            8              
S145144       DUMAN, MARILYN M.    13002154            2
S144413        CRUZ, ISABELLA      13002154            2
S145151        CASTRO, MARIO C.    13002154            5
S145151        CASTRO, MARIO C.    13002154            1
S142058      RILLERA, FREDILYN B.  13002155            10
S142058      RILLERA, FREDILYN B.  13002155            2
```

As you can see, the next row of the original order has the same records but different Quantity. This means that the Quantity another row is the FreeGoods. But also in some other rows, there can be records that has no succeeding records for the FreeGoods. I am not so literate on linq. How can I groupby and select it to make something like this?

```
  SINo          AccountName       ProductCode       Quantity      FreeGoods
S145144       DUMAN, MARILYN M.    13002154            8             2
S144413        CRUZ, ISABELLA      13002154            2
S145151        CASTRO, MARIO C.    13002154            5             1
S142058      RILLERA, FREDILYN B.  13002155            10            2
```

There is no unique property in each record. The properties e.g. SINo, AccountName, Product can be duplicated in each row.

Comment: Is it always two rows in that order? show what you have tried so far.

Comment: are you sure that for each product code there will be exactly two records in which second one will contains the free goods.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes in that order, but it can be repeated in some other rows (e.g. the customer ordered again the product). I also updated my question

Comment: @jitender Yes not that exact. But there are some records that has no next record for free goods. I will update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Linq query give me expected result. Hopefully it will help you

```
List<Row> list = new List<Row>();
//add data to list
//then execute this linq query
list.GroupBy(x => x.SINo).Select(y=> new Row
            {
                AccountName = y.First().AccountName,
                ProductCode = y.First().ProductCode,
                Quantity = y.First().Quantity,
                SINo = y.First().SINo,
                FreeGoods = y.Count() > 1 ? y.Last().Quantity : 0
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you put a new column hasFreeGoods as that will provide you a more clean solution

On current structure.I assume there will be maximum two records for each product

```
var groups=from r in Rows group r by new {
r.ProductCode,
r.SINo,
r.AccountName
} into gr;

groups.select(g => new {
g.Key.ProductCode,
g.Key.SINo,
g.Key.AccountName,
Quantity=g.First().Quantity,
FreeGoods =g.Count()>1 ? g.Last().Quentity :0   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Just a slight difference from the previous answers:

```
 var result = list.GroupBy(p => p.SINo,                             
                             (key, g) => new { 
                             SINo = g.Key,
                             ProductCode = g.First().ProductCode,
                             AccountName = g.First().AccountName,
                             Quantity = g.First().Quantity,
                             FreeGoods = g.Count() > 1 ? g.Last().Quantity : 0 
                             }).ToList();
```